# MongoDB and rmongodb. Get size of find instead of returning all results

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with >100k documents (this number will keep growing). Each document has a few fields that are a single value, and about 50 fields that are each an array of length 1000. I am analyzing results in R using rmongodb.

In rmongodb I am using `mongo.find.all()` with query set to some combination of criteria to search for, and fields set to a subset of the fields to return. The equivalent in the mongo shell would be something like:

```
db.collection.find({query1 : "value1", query2 : "value2"},{field1 : 1, field2 : 1, field3 : 1})
```

This returns a data.frame of the results, which I do some post-processing on and end up with a data.table.

What I would like to do is add some safeguards to the query. If the query is broad, and the fields returned are many of the larger array fields, the resulting data.table can be in the tens of GB. This might be what is expected, but I would like to add some flags or error checking so that someone doesn't accidentally try to return hundreds of GB at once.

I know I can get a count of the number of documents that match a query (`mongo.count` in rmongodb, `db.collection.find({...},{...}).count()` in the shell). I can also get an average document size (`db.collection.stats().avgObjSize`).

What I do not know how to do, nor do I know if it is possible, is to get the size (in MB, not number) of a find before the find is actually returned. Since I am often returning only a subset of the fields, the count and avgObjSize don't give me a very accurate estimate of how big the resulting data.table will be. The size would need to take into account both the query and the fields.

Is there a command like `db.collection.find({},{}).sizeOf()` that would return the size in MB of my find(query,fields)? The only options I can see are `count()` and `size()` both of which return the number of documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through cursor manually (as it done in [mongo.cursor.to.list](https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/blob/master/R/mongo_cursor.R#L32-L46) ) and iteratively check the size of the resulting object. Something like this:

```
LIMIT = 1024 * 1024 * 1024
res_size = 0
mongo.cursor.to.list_with_check <- function (cursor, 
                                             keep.ordering = TRUE, 
                                             limit = LIMIT) {
    # make environment to avoid extra copies
    e <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
    i <- 1
    while (mongo.cursor.next(cursor) && res_size < limit) {
        val = mongo.bson.to.list(mongo.cursor.value(cursor))
        res_size = res_size + object.size(val)
        assign(x = as.character(i),
               value = val, envir = e)
        i <- i + 1
    }
    # convert back to list
    res <- as.list(e)
    if (isTRUE(keep.ordering)) setNames(res[order(as.integer(names(res)))], NULL)
    else setNames(res, NULL)
}
```

After that you can convert it into `data.table` via `data.table::rbindlist()`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy. I was hoping it was possible to have mongo return the size without transferring any of the data. I don't want to set a hard limit, but perhaps a flagged warning along the lines of "Warning, returned data frame will be 16GB, do you want to continue?"

I think what could work though is to use your idea above, but return just one document. Since in my project each document will return the same size, I can combine a mongo.count() and object.size of a single document to get the total expected size, and then have a setting based on that calculation. It avoids transferring too much.

Comment: Of course if sizes of your records are mostly similar, you can use `mongo.count` multiplied by average size of a document. There is no solution without data reading/transfer.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that might be the case, but thought I would check first. Would be nice if there was an equivalent to `mongo.count` or `db.collection.find(query).count()` that would return the size of the query/field. Your idea of using `mongo.cursor.to.list` to return one at a time, combined with a `mongo.count` seems like the best option. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can write script for this flexibility required in this situation: 
(I assume that you wanna return 1GB maximum)

```
    //limit 1GB
    var mbLimit = 1024*1024;
    //find number to show and round it to an int
    var numberShow = (mbLimit/db.restaurants.stats().avrObjSize) | 0;
    //limit the query
    db.restaurants.find({
       {query1 : "value1", query2 : "value2"},{field1 : 1, field2 : 1, field3 : 1}
        }).limit(numberShow)
```

Comment: Thank you for you response. Your answer would work well if I were returning all fields. However, I am often returning 1 of the 50 fields that are a long array, in which case my average returned document size would be ~1/50th of the avgObjSize. Or I might be returning just some of the single value fields and none of the larger arrays, in which case the returned objects are very small compared to avgObjSize. Is there a way go get avgObjSize while specifying a subset of the fields?